# integer division in C

Tags: c

Following is a code segment i am using:

```
int q;
int cacheline = 64;
int min;

q = cacheline/min;
```

when run, this always gets an exception for `q`. i want the quotient part i.e for 64/20 i want 3 and don't care about the remainder. i am at loss about the error since `int` should truncate.

Comment: Is `min` ever initialized?

Comment: This question is tagged as C, but if you are getting an exception I 'd say it's not in C... In other news, does `min` have a non-zero value?

Comment: Tell me: do you expect any particular result from `64/0` ?

Comment: What is the precise error message you get? C does not have exceptions.

Comment: With this type of question, a code fragment is useless.  We need to see a complete program that can be compiled and run.  Cutting your code down to the minimal test program that still produces the problem is helpful, and a valuable skill in its own right, but not as important as giving us something we can test without making any guesses about what you didn't show us.

Comment: @Matrinho more like 64 / uninitialized :p

Comment: @Marlon Or maybe 64/0. There are some guaranteed initializations in C.

Comment: By *exception*, OP means a signal or fault like `SIGFPE` or whatever the Windows equivalent is (I believe the Windows crash dialog uses the word "exception" in it).

Answer (score 2):

You should post the error and format your code correctly.

But your problem is that min is uninitialized.

That's obviously not your code though since that's not compliable.

Answer (score 1):

Min needs to be initialized.  It is currently undefined.

In order to get the truncated integer division, all you would need to do is to initialize min and do the division.  The fact that it is dividing by and being placed into an int will cause the remainder part to drop.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me.... so as Falmarri,Joey, Mark said check your code !!
        `int q;
 int c = 64;
 int m = 20;
 q = c/m;
 printf("output:%d",q);`